# Regex - Extract substring from within string

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

Would appreciate some help with this extraction for Google Data Studio (RE2):

I need to extract everything from this string between the "1. " and the "https://www.journorequests.com"

```
"- Health & Fitness ---
**1.** Phee Waterfield (https://www.twitter.com/pheecetious) 
Does anyone know of any mental health accelerators or incubators? #journorequest #techjpr #prrequest
https://www.journorequests.com/redirect… & Fitness&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitter.com%2Fpheecetious%2Fstatus%2F920331054342463488&medium=instant_alert"
```

Comment: what language, regex engine are you using?

Comment: RE2 for Google Data Studio

Comment: I assume the `**` before and after the `1.` are an attempt to bold the `1.` and not part of the actual input? And I also assume the `"` at the beginning and end of the string aren't part of the actual input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is.

```
^.*?\d.(.*?)(journorequests\.com){1}
```

This will return the content you need in the first capturing group.

[See my work here.](https://regex101.com/r/KIhILS/2)

Also you might want to do some reading on *[Regular Expressions, Capturing groups](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)*

Comment: Thanks Josh

I made an error in my question (now corrected)

I need to extract everything between "1. " and "https://www.journorequests.com"

Sorry :(

Comment: updated feel free to fork and play with my work on regex101